# Finding string into a ByteArray. Is it a simple solution for that?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, air, arrays

What is the simpliest way to find an occurance of some sequance of bytes (string) in a long byte array?

thank you in advance!!

**UPD:** I tried to do

```
my_byte_array.toString().indexOf(needle_string);
```

the problem is that in flash/air string consist of utf8 characters, so indexOf will return value different from offset of "string" in a byte array (actually it's zip archive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the array is long enough that you don’t want to convert it to a string, I guess I’d just bite the bullet and do something like this:

```
function byteArrayContainsString
  (haystack : ByteArray, needleString : String) : Boolean
{
  const needle : ByteArray = new ByteArray

  needle.writeUTFBytes(needleString)

  return byteArrayIndexOf(haystack, needle) !== -1
}

function byteArrayIndexOf
  (haystack : ByteArray, needle : ByteArray) : int
{
  search: for (var i : int = 0; i < haystack.length; ++i) {
    for (var j : int = 0; j < needle.length; ++j)
      if (haystack[i + j] !== needle[j])
        continue search

    return i
  }

  return -1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this would work:

```
//needle_string is the sequence you want to find
my_byte_array.toString().indexOf(needle_string);
```

This will return -1 if the sequence is not found, and otherwise the index at which the sequence has been found.

Comment: Thank you! it's the first thing I tried, the problem is that in flash/air string consist of utf8 characters, so indexOf will return value different from offset of "string" in a byte array (actually it's zip archive). I'll update my ansver in order not to confuse others.

Comment: Yeah I guess that would be the very first thing to try, as it is quite obvious... sorry but I don't quite understand your update.

Comment: But it's similar to my content?)